# Reuse(Null/Nothing/Empty) Employee ID after being deleted

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want my delete button to make my Employee ID empty/nothing/null so that I can reuse the numbers I had put to the Employee ID cell from the row that has been deleted.  [in here I had already deleted the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGWci.png)[here is the update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOKom.png) employeeID is not set as primary key.

```
   Private Sub BtnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

        If tbxUser_id.Text.Count < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to Delete Yet", "Notice!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbx").ConnectionString
            Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE [EmmeSubic].[dbo].[UserDetails] SET isDeleted = 1 where id = @user_id", conn)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tbxUser_id.Text

                    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete this records?", "Notice!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                        conn.Open()
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        UserDetailBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
                        conn.Close()
                    End If

                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: In your code you are setting Employee_ID to `tbxEmployeeId` rather than nothing. Your question doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: i just forgot to delete it. originally, I just want the Cell Employee ID that is on my dbase table UserDetails to be nothing or " " so it wont conflict on my button "save" since I am using employeeID as validation for Employee already exist

Comment: Put the MessageBox *outside* the `Using conn` statement. Don't declare the objects if the user isn't really going to run the delete.

Comment: Generally speaking it is a terribly bad idea to reuse employee IDs. Imagine I would have worked for about a year for your company and created / modified 100000 records where I'm registered as the creator / modifier, probably not only on the records themselves where you maybe could count on the referential integrity but also in log texts, xml blobs etc. and now I leave and somebody else inherits all that legacy from me, being blamed for changes they never made?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. sorry for I am just starting in this kind of industry. For what I know this employeeID will only be used for their other current Employees. Meaning to say only with specified speciality on the same field employees. I just dont understand why would they be blamed for the changes they never made for instance, the modifiers have their own account. I just made employeeid like that because whenever I delete and create a new, and save, the  message box "employeeID already exist" pops up although it is deleted meaning to say I still have them on my dbase. any thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **user_id** to null or '' in your update command.

```
UPDATE [EmmeSubic].[dbo].[UserDetails] SET
  isDeleted = 1
  , user_id = NULL
WHERE id = @user_id
```

Comment: employee ID is what I am trying to make as null so i put it like Using cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE [EmmeSubic].[dbo].[UserDetails] SET EmployeeID = Null, isDeleted = 1 where id = @user_id", conn). Thankyou